# (Magento 2) How to halt sales

Tags: sales

I need to halt sales for some days. Which is the best way to do that? I don't see anything in configuration. I wouldn't like to have the site appearing as being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the onepage checkout in the configuration In

System >> Configuration >> Sales >> Checkout >> Checkout Options >> Disable Onepage Checkout.

Remove add to cart button logic in
template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Comment: Exact changes done: 
1) disabled Onepage Checkout (in Stores, not in System)
2) addtocart.phtml file emptied in template/catalog/product/view
3) list.phtml file changed in template/catalog/product: test `code` if ($_product->isSaleable()) `/code` was added with its opposite so that it's never true: `code` if ($_product->isSaleable() && ! $_product->isSaleable())  `/code`